# How to convert a powershell script to opensource `.exe`?

Tags: installer, powershell, file-extension

To make an installation of opensource software for the Windows platform single click, I am trying to convert the `setup.ps1` into a `setup.exe` file. (To make a powershell script executable in a single (double) click, the user might/is still required [perform additional actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635/why-are-my-powershell-scripts-not-running?noredirect=1&lq=1)). So to do that I downloaded `PS2Exe` from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5. After running the following command in the correct folder in powershell:

```
.\ps2exe.ps1 .\setup.ps1 .\target.exe
```

The exe is indeed created. But upon inspection I found that the `target.exe` file is not inspectable with e.g. Winrar, whereas the latest installer of Eclipse, `eclipse-inst-win64.exe`, is.

Hence my question is:
How can I convert the `setup.ps1` to a single click `setup.exe` that is inspectable*/opensource?

*With inspectable, I mean a computer illiterate can still relatively easily see what the original lines of code and files are, e.g. no bytecode/no assembly etc.

**Approaches**

1. Thanks to the comments, I learned the reason the eclipse installer that is used as an example, consists of a self extracting zip file. After a short inspection I have not yet found an example of a self extracting zip file that is able to execute a powershell script without requiring user input. Such an example could suggest a feasible solution would be to create a self extracting zip that executes the `setup.ps1` but it appears unlikely.
2. Wix installer has [an option to include powershells into an MSI file](https://david.gardiner.net.au/2014/05/powershell-wix-extension.html).

   2.1 I have yet to determine whether it is also able to create a
   `setup.exe` file that allows the `setup.ps1` to be execute, and
   whether it can execute the powershell without requiring extra user
   actions.

   2.2 I have yet to determine whether the `setup.exe` is (easily) reverse-engineerable, it appears ORCA is able to reverse engineer an MSI installer file, but I am not yet sure whether that qualifies as "Open Source" as it might be possible that different code/file combinations yielded the same MSI.
3. Based on https://4sysops.com/archives/creating-an-exe-for-your-powershell-scripts-using-winrar/ as suggested in the comments, I created an exe with sfx that unpacks the `setup.ps1` file to: `E:/some folder with a space/` using comments:

```
Path="E:\some folder with a space\target/"
SavePath
Setup=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -sta -noexit -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file "E:\some folder with a space\target\setup.ps1"
Silent=1
Overwrite=1
```

without adding an icon. However when the exe is executed it returns:

> ````
>     Windows PowerShell
>     Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
>     lxrun : The term 'lxrun' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
>     the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>     At E:\18-09-19 Document structure\personal\Programming\tools\powershellToExe\target\setup.ps1:1
> char:1
>     + lxrun /install /y
>     + ~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (lxrun:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException ```
> ````

Much like powershell is in a different path than the `setup.ps1` script that is executed. When I open a powershell via Start>Powershell, enter `E:`followed by `cd "E:\some folder with a space\target" and run`./setup.ps1`the unpacked`setup.ps1` runs fine. So I checked with command:

```
[bool](([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match "S-1-5-32-544")
```

[whether the difference between the powershells was in administrative priviliges](https://superuser.com/questions/749243/detect-if-powershell-is-running-as-administrator), which it was not.

The content of the powershell script is:

```
lxrun /install /y
lxrun /setdefaultuser testlinuxname /y
lxrun /setdefaultuser root /y
bash -c "echo 'testlinuxname:mypassword' | chpasswd"
bash -c "sudo echo 'testlinuxname ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers"
wsl sudo apt update
bash -c "echo 'yes' | sudo apt install default-jre"
lxrun /setdefaultuser testlinuxname /y
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

To investigate the possible reason for the execution difficulties the SFX conversion from `ps1` to `exe` yield, I will include an `echo` of the current directory in the `setup.ps1` to inspect the paths which powershell works in.

Comment: you can only see the "code" because eclipse-inst-win64.exe is a self extracting zip.

Comment: @Ewan, thank you. I could not find any examples of a self extracting zip executing a powershell script. I will use your comment to include approaches in my question.

Comment: https://4sysops.com/archives/creating-an-exe-for-your-powershell-scripts-using-winrar/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759456/creating-an-executable-exe-file-from-a-powershell-script/4629494#4629494

Answer (score 2):

Credits go to @Jotunn and @Ewan. As listed in [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759456/creating-an-executable-exe-file-from-a-powershell-script/4629494#4629494) provided by @Ewan, the answer of @Jotunn provided a solution. Powergui allows conversion of `setup.ps1` to `setup.exe`. The verified steps as described are:

> Open your script in the PowerGUI Script Editor > Tools > Compile
>   script.

Then your powershell script gets executed in a Console Window Host if you run it. The compiled `setup.exe` is still inspectable by for example winrar.